# Ubuntu and Windows common files

Tags: dual-boot

I am currently thinking about installing dual boot ubuntu and windows 8.1
And I have like 190GB Music file. Is there anyway that I can access both from ubuntu or windows to the music files without copying these files to ubuntu and windows. I have one SSD and one HDD I want to install ubuntu to ssd and windows to hdd.

Comment: You can always mount the windows partition under a path in Linux. Check which type of file system you have on windows

Comment: How exactly ? I am newbie at Linux

Comment: Why not install Windows and Ubuntu on the SSD and data on HDD.

Comment: I have 120GB ssd and 110 usable , so I don't think It's enough for both ? ıs it?

Comment: plenty, I use 50 GB for each install.  Havent run out yet

Comment: So let's say I installed both on SSD then I copied my music to hdd on windows can I acces it from ubuntu?

Comment: Yes.  Ill answer your question in a bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the SSD, you'll want to partition it so it has about half the space for both OS.  When you use the HDD format it as NTFS and then just mount it with Ubuntu.  Simple :)

**Edit**

Your drives are separate devices, Ubuntu and other *nix OS use a file system which basically references all the devices in your computer as if they were like files and folders in one system.

To accomplish installing both windows an Ubuntu on the same drive, you'll want to install windows first, but set it so it only uses about half the space on the SSD.  Then once Windows is installed you can install Ubuntu and set it up to use the rest of the SSD for its main EXT4 format storage system and the SWAP, if you want to use SWAP on your SSD.

Once both Operating Systems are installed, you can use either Windows or Ubuntu to format the remaining HDD in NTFS format.

Windows will likely mount this disk automatically as E: or F: perhaps.  However in Ubuntu you'll mount this disk by clicking the icon for it in your Nautilus file-browser window or in the Unity Task bar if it shows up there.  After this disk has been mounted you can find it in the file system at `/media/<volume name here>`  where `<volume name here>` is replaced with a name of your disk being either the label or an ID number.

**Edit 2**

For UEFI, Ubuntu should install just fine.  As far as I know Ubuntu ships its latest versions with EFI compatible boot loaders (grub-pc/grub2) 
After you install Ubuntu, if you install it second, you should get a boot menu like the regular GRUB boot menu. 
However, I personally have not installed a dual boot on EFI/UEFI systems and so I don't know if there are any quirks or manual steps you should definitely know about.

Comment: Can I do this with UFEI  windows?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  First off, I use a 3 partition HDD.  50 gb both allocated to Windows and Ubuntu.  Ubuntu in the ext4 Jorunal file system and Windows in the NTFS file system.  My data part uses an NTFS File system so it can be read by Windows.  In order to do this, you should make a live usb.

Once you are running in your live usb in either ubuntu or windows.  At which point you will format your HDD as NTFS.  Once that is done make a folder and copy your music to the HDD.

At this point you can now safely install Windows then Install Ubuntu.  Windows will always mount anything it see, where as Ubuntu will recongize it, but clicking the HDD icon once on the Unity Taskbar will mount it.

As a reminder Windows by default will never see the Z drive Ubuntu uses.  So if you need files from Ubuntu make certain you copy them or download them to your Data Drive.  Ubuntu wil see Windows however.

Comment: For installing ubuntu on SSD for example I limited ubuntu at 30gb and windows at 90gb. I have 750gb HDD empty I named it as D: on windows and throw all my music into it. And I mounted it as you told on ubuntu. Now my question is  when I download some files  or install some software on ubuntu is it going to use the ssd or hdd can I choose that as I can on windows. Cuz I used ubuntu for a month before and I couldn't manage partition on ubuntu It showed my whole HDD as one (this is before I bought ssd and installed ubuntu on my 750gb hdd)

Comment: You will as default download in to Ubuntu based install location.   You can however tell Ubuntu what location you want your libraries to be.  It won't be as annoying as what you did in windows.  The concept will be the same.